# Condition is never met when no queryString is presented

Tags: vb.net

Either none of these will be presented or one will be presented. When none is presented the condition is never hit

```
    Private _page As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("Page"))
    Private _pge As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Page.RouteData.Values("page"))

    Private Function getPage() As String
        Dim ret As String = ""
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_page) = True AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(_pge) = True Then
            ret = 1
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(_page) = False AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(_pge) = True Then
            ret = _page
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(_page) = True AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(_pge) = False Then
            ret = _pge
        End If
        Return ret
    End Function
```

Comment: turn `Option Strict` on and do yourself a favour.

Comment: Also, `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_page) = True AndAlso ...` is rather more verbose than needed. What's wrong with `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_page) AndAlso ...`? (Equally, `Not` is usually preferred as an alternative to comparing with `False`)

Answer (score 0):

Might be it cozed by . you always **return _page**

Try this ..

```
Private Function getPage() As String
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_page) = True AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(_pge) = True Then
            _page = 1
            Return _page
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(_page) = False AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(_pge) = True Then
            Return _page
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(_page) = True AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(_pge) = False Then
            Return _pge
        Else
            Return _page
        End If

    End Function
```

Comment: For your edited Q -- Mean that you met FALSE - FALSE condition , So you get empty string ..

Comment: I'm still not getting empty string

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you problem is, can't tell from the question but, I'd rewrite the function like this.

**Note** in your original function, you return `_page` when it is `Nothing` or empty.

```
Private Function GetPage() As String
    Dim pageHasValue = Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_page)
    Dim pgeHasValue = Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_pge)

    If pageHasValue AndAlso pgeHasValue Then
        Return "1"
    End If

    If pgeHasValue Then
        Return _pge
    End If

    If pageHasValue Then
        Return _page
    End If

    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

Comment: I'm still not getting empty string with this

Comment: @ruffone what do you get? Show the declarations of `_page` and `_pge` and tell us what values they have assigned.

Comment: I updated the code the value is "http://example.com, http://example.com/route" as opposed to "http://example.com?page=1, http://example.com/route/1"